# how to optimize for each loop in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need to classify each row of a range accordingly with another range. The script works just fine. But it takes too much time even if it has no more than 300 rows. E.g. 298 rows take more than 2 minutes.

In order to achieve the classification, the script was built with a for each loop inside another one. All is done in the same worksheet called `WSSeg`. I tried to use all the good practices that I know of.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Input_Classification()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim TBLClassification As ListObject
    Dim TBLReference As ListObject

    Dim rClassificationCell As Range
    Dim rClassification As Range

    Dim rReferenceCell As Range
    Dim rReference As Range

    Set TBLClassification = WSSeg.ListObjects("TBClass")    
    Set rClassification = TBL.ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange

    Set TBLReference = WSSeg.ListObjects("TBResumo")
    Set rReference = TBL.ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange

    For Each rClassificationCell In rClassification
        For Each rReferenceCell In rReference
            If rClassificationCell.Offset(0, -1).Value <= rReferenceCell.Value Then
                rClassificationCell.Value = rReferenceCell.Value
            End If
        Next rReferenceCell
    Next rClassificationCell

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I expect the run time code to be shorter. I don't know if I have to use another logic system. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add the values in your range to an Array, then compare from there. You're making multiple calls to the worksheet object slows things down, especially when you're writing to the worksheet multiple times like you are. So you'd also want to place your new values in an array then write that array to the worksheet once instead of everytime your If statement returns true.

Comment: And I've noticed your `.EnableEvents` and `.ScreenUpdating`. You forgot what is usually the most taxing of all, `.Calculation`. You are writing to the worksheet many many times within your loops. Every single write to the worksheet causes a recalc to occur, and your loop cannot progress until the calculation has finished . However, if your loop is dependent on the newly calculated values, this wouldn't be appropriate to change the property to manual - but that's likely the largest cause of your slow code. But again, using arrays as I've mentioned above is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to modify the code, it takes only 0.04 Secs with two tables of around 500 rows.

Tried to keep the replacement logic same as the original, But may please check the same, as i am little confused about the same. If find otherwise, please modify them to your need. Also Could not understand the what is `TBL` in cases with both the tables and assumed the obvious.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Input_Classification()
    Dim WSSeg As Worksheet
    Dim TBLClassification As ListObject
    Dim TBLReference As ListObject
    Dim rClassification As Range

    Dim SrcArr As Variant, TrgArr As Variant, SrcCel As Variant
    Dim i As Long, Tm As Double
    Set WSSeg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Tm = Timer
    Set TBLClassification = WSSeg.ListObjects("TBClass")
    Set rClassification = TBLClassification.ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange.Resize(TBLClassification.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, 2)
    TrgArr = rClassification.Value

    Set TBLReference = WSSeg.ListObjects("TBResumo")
    SrcArr = TBLReference.ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange.Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(TrgArr, 1)
        For Each SrcCel In SrcArr
            If TrgArr(i, 1) <= SrcCel Then
                TrgArr(i, 2) = SrcCel
            End If
        Next SrcCel
    Next i


rClassification.Value = TrgArr
Debug.Print "Seconds taken " & Timer - Tm
End Sub
```

Since I personally don't prefer to keep calculations, event processing and screen updating off (in normal cases) i haven't added that standard lines. However you may use these standard techniques, depending on the working file condition.